# Tangent Circles either completly inside or outside one another?

Tags: geometry

Assume there are two circles $X$ and $Y$, with only one point that touches at $A$.

How can we prove that $X$ is entirely on the outside of $Y$, or in the interior of $Y$? (with the exception of point $A$)

Comment: Hint: Consider a point P that is inside both circles and let the center of circle x be X and center of circle y be Y. Now there is something that can be said about d(P,X)+d(P,Y) and the fact that A is the only point the circles have in common. Now reach a contradiction...

Comment: What is the relationship of the tangent line to a circle at a point to the circle’s radius at that point?

Comment: What do you mean by that? How can I take a point P if the 2 circles are entirely on the exterior of each other?

Answer (score 0):

If two unequal circles in the same plane have only one point in common, and the lesser circle is neither wholly inside nor wholly outside the greater circle, then the lesser circle must be partly inside and partly outside the greater circle. But circles which have only one point in common are tangent to each other, and conversely (Euclid III, Def.3 & Prop.13). Since the lesser circle is partly inside and partly outside the greater circle, their circumferences must intersect, and therefore cut one another in two (and only two) points (Euclid III,10). But this contradicts the supposition that the circles have only one point in common, i.e. that they are tangent to each other. Therefore the lesser circle is not partly inside and partly outside, but wholly inside or wholly outside the greater circle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it's obvious that they would have two points in common, but how can you prove it?

Comment: @j.stat--I've tried to make the argument a little more explicit, at the risk of overworking it. I agree it's close to obvious that they have two points in common. Of the truly obvious no proof is necessary or possible. Euclid proves circles don't intersect in more points than two, but not that they can't intersect in just one point. I guess he considered that obvious--reserved for tangent circles, which "meet but do not cut one another".